# Batch file to rename extracted file if same name already exists

Tags: command-line, cmd, winzip

I work for a financial institution that pulls reports from out an outside source. I have an extremely basic batch file that checks folders for any zip file, extracts them to a different location, and moves the zip file to an "old" folder after extraction.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinZip\WZUNZIP.EXE" -d -o -sXXXXXXXXX C:\SFTP\ReportingAnalytics\Accounting\*.zip \\servername\Share2\Reporting_Analytics\Accounting\
MOVE C:\SFTP\ReportingAnalytics\Accounting\*.zip C:\SFTP\ReportingAnalyticsOld\Accounting
```

During the week, this works great. The problem is occurring on the weekends. These reports come over daily...unfortunately, with the same file name each day. So during the week, someone is working the report and there is no problem. On the weekends, no one works the report and they are getting overwritten (Friday's report comes in Saturday morning, gets overwritten on Sunday when Saturday's report comes in).

Is there an easy way to automatically rename these files upon extraction? ie AccountingReport1, AccountingReport2, and so on...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\one"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*.zip") DO (
 ECHO("C:\Program Files\WinZip\WZUNZIP.EXE" -d -o -sXXXXXXXXX C:\SFTP\ReportingAnalytics\Accounting\%%a \\servername\Share2\Reporting_Analytics\Accounting\%%~na\
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required WZUNZIP commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO("...WZUNZIP` to `"...WZUNZIP` to actually create the directories and extract the files.

You don't tell us how many files/directories are in the archive or indicate their names, and your use of `-d -o` implies there's a whole slough, hence this approach is to extract each `.zip` file to a new directory, *nameofzip* under `\\servername\S...s\Accounting`